# Repeat ruby html?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following html, for example, and I need to make it repeat several times. Without using parcials and other stuff, how can I easily repeat it?

```
<div>This is a div</div>
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
<%= repeat 4 times %>
    <div>This is a div</div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ruby `times` method:

```
<% 4.times do %>
    <div>This is a div</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Don't need `each` here

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby 

3.times do 
  puts "This will be printed 3 times" 
end 

print "Enter a number: " 
num = gets.chomp.to_i 

num.times do 
  puts "Ruby is great!" 
end
```

This is an example of times loop in ruby. Hope it helped